# use of other columns as arguments to function in summarize_at()

Tags: r, dplyr

This works great:

```
> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize_at(vars(disp, hp), weighted.mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl  disp    hp
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  4.00   105  82.6
2  6.00   183 122  
3  8.00   353 209
```

But now I want to use one of the columns from mtcars as the w argument to weighted.mean. Sadly, the obvious attempt fails:

```
> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize_at(vars(disp, hp), weighted.mean, w = wt)
Error in dots_list(...) : object 'wt' not found
```

Even though wt is, indeed, part of mtcars. How can I use other columns as arguments to a function within summarize_at()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the `funs()` syntax:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
        summarize_at(vars(disp, hp), funs(weighted.mean(.,wt)))
#    cyl  disp    hp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  4.00   110  83.4
#2  6.00   185 122  
#3  8.00   362 209
```

Comment: Would love some more explanation on how `funs` works! Where does it evaluate the wrapped functions such that it knows to use the right groups for `wt`? I usually use `function(x)` or `~` formula notation, but neither works in this case, I think because of the `group_by`.

Comment: With multiple arguments and grouping, you need to wrap your summary functions inside `funs()`, otherwise the extra args are not evaluated for each group it seems. See `?summarise_at` for more info.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: It looks like funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0. Any other ideas about how to do this without using funs()?