# Use of other columns as arguments to function in summarize_at() and summarize_all() without funs()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for an alternative to this (which was provided as a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395025/use-of-other-columns-as-arguments-to-function-in-summarize-at)) that does not use `funs()` since `funs()` is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
        summarize_at(vars(disp, hp), funs(weighted.mean(.,wt)))
#    cyl  disp    hp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  4.00   110  83.4
#2  6.00   185 122  
#3  8.00   362 209
```

Comment: use `list()`...

Comment: It might be worth noting that `dplyr 1.0.0` will be released tomorrow, and `summarize()` has been upgraded: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I didn't know that! Looks like the updates don't really impact this question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the R warning says, you have to use (in this case) a list of lambdas

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(disp, hp), list(~weighted.mean(., wt)))
```