# Use of other columns as arguments to function in summarize_if()

Tags: r, dplyr

This works great (see it as a solution for using `list()` instead of `vars()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798715/use-of-other-columns-as-arguments-to-function-in-summarize-at-and-summarize-al)):

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(disp, hp), list(~weighted.mean(., wt)))
```

However, in a very similar situation using `summarize_if()`, it does not work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_if(is.numeric, list(~weighted.mean(., wt)))

Error in weighted.mean.default(., wt) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with what you are naming this new variable. This works:

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     summarize_if(is.numeric, list(tmp = ~weighted.mean(., wt)))
```

See the naming section [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) and issues that have been noted [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2243) for more details.

Comment: Well that works, but now there's "_tmp" appended onto the column names of all the summarized variables, which is really annoying.

Comment: Agreed - I think that `summarise_if` tries to construct the new name by concatenating along the lines of e.g. `paste("disp", "tmp", sep = "_")`. When a name isn't specified for the function, I think it might try to use `" "` instead of `"tmp"` (at least that is what I gather from that git-post); it feels like this might be where the issue is coming from?

Comment: As to removing the "_tmp", try adding `%>% rename_at(vars(ends_with("_tmp")), list(~stringr::str_replace(., "_tmp", "")))`